# What's [happen to] in this?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I've always thought that [happen to] is the phrasal verb indicating chance, which can be replaced as [by chance] such as...

1. I happen to have some money in my pocket.

   = I have some money in my pocket by chance.
2. Do you happen to be a teacher?

   = Are you a teacher by any chance?

But, sometimes I stumble across what I can't use the above rule. For example...

> A,B,C are at the table where B prepared a meal for C.
>
> A: (Went ahead and tasted some) It's so good!
>
> B: Hey! Don't just eat it without asking! This **happens to** be for C.

Here, the meal can't be something prepared by chance, more like it's fixed by B on purpose. Then what's the exact meaning of [happen to] in this sentence? And what would you recommend as the alternative words rather than [by chance]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Happen to do something* has a few meanings. You know *to do something* ***by chance***:

> I happen to have some money in my pocket. *(I even didn't plan it)*
>
> I happened to meet an old friend in town. *(I met him by chance)*

In spoken English, the phrase can be used for **asking** something **politely**:

> Do you happen to be a teacher?
>
> Do you happen to have an extra pencil?

It can also be used for **expressing an opinion firmly**, because you are angry, and this is the meaning you are asking about (it's common in spoken English too):

> Hey! Don't just eat it without asking! This happens to be for C.*(the speaker is obviously annoyed)*
>
> I happen to live here too – don’t leave your rubbish everywhere!

Source: [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/happen-to-do-something)